# How to map web services of a port with Amazon SQS

Tags: java, android, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a django web App running on apache2 port number:8001.

I hosted this app on amazon cloud in ubuntu machine.

I get data on this port from a client application(Android App).

Some time I get so many client request to submit data same time.

Due to that there is a change of packet drop.

So I want to use Amazon Simple Queuing Services(SQS) to ensure delivery of data without any delay or drop of packet.

My question:

Can I map the port or services that running on port 8001 with Amazon SQS.

So that I get all the coming request through Queue.

Is there any API or something to do this in Java/Android.